# IFileRepositoryProvider to deal with uploaded files

Tags: c#, .net, azure, file-io, stream

Depending on which environment our system is hosted in, it will use a different 'file system' to manage user-uploaded files.  For example, in our development environment we use the windows file system but in production we use Azure blob storage.

Using the provider model, I have created the following interface:

```
public interface IFileRepositoryProvider
{
    void SaveFile(string fileName, Stream fileStream);

    void DeleteFile(string fileName);

    bool Exists(string fileName);

    Stream GetStream(string fileName);
}
```

- The details of how files are saved/deleted/etc are completely encapsulated by the concrete implementations of `IFileRepositoryProvider`.
- There are some limitations with Azure blob storage.  I can't necessarily provide a direct "URI" to a file, like we could if it is hosted in some virtual directory on a web server.  **For this reason, I decided to work entirely with streams.**  It is up to the client code to deal with the stream as needed.

Questions:

- Would `FileStream` or `MemoryStream` be better?
- Is there a benefit to rather exposing the files as byte arrays?
- Can you see any serious shortcomings of this approach?

Comment: When running in Windows Azure will the BLOBs be stored in a public container or private?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you use FileStream or MemoryStream or some other stream type really doesn't matter; Your interface should just accept a Stream and can then handle various different inputs.

I would say that streams are more flexible than byte arrays. One thing to look out for, though, is that you will often have to remember to set position=0 on your stream before passing them to the interface.

You should also think about async and about whether you want to handle proper streaming - i.e. writing to Azure blob storage while still receiving data from the client (this can be a bit tricky with the way the azure storage API works).

The one thing I would say is that your interface looks like you are trying to make Azure blob storage behave like a file system, with the emphasis on file names. There are certain limitations in Azure blob storage about what you can call the files; In essence, your "name" needs to be URI encoded. I have found that a better approach is to embrace the idea that Azure blob storage effectively works off an identifier and then try to emulate that on the file system. So, when you 'save' a file, you will pass in a name and a stream and will be returned a string which is an identifier (it is actually a URI or part of a URI). The client has to store that identifier and will have to present that identifier when they want to retrieve the file.

The other benefit of this is that your implementation is responsible for generating the identifier and can therefore include a Guid in the identifier to avoid any name clashes.

Finally, if you are planning on storing a large number of files in Azure Blob Storage you should be aware that it is slow to browse and virtually impossible to search. So, to make support easier, think carefully about how you construct your identifier. While technically Blob Storage is flat, you can emulate a folder structure by including "/" in the identifier. So, for example, you may create an identifier like year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "/" + guid + '/' + Uri.Encode(filename).
Or you may include some context specific information in the identifier.

Comment: There is a method in the Windows Azure Storage Client Library to check if a blob exists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.exists.aspx